# Postgres join involving tables having join condition defined on an text array

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables in postgresql 
One table is of the form

```
Create table table1(
  ID serial PRIMARY KEY,
  Type []Text
)



Create table table2(
type text,
sellerID int 
)
```

Now i want to get all the rows from table1 which are having type same that in table2 but the problem is that in table1 the type is an array.

Answer (score 0):

In case the type in the table has an identifiable delimiter like ',' ,';' etc. you can rewrite the query as regexp_split_to_table(type,',') or versions later than 9.5 unnest function can be use too.

For eg.,

```
select * from 
( select id ,regexp_split_to_table(type,',') from table1)table1
inner join 
select * from table2 
on trim(table1.type) = trim(table2.type)
```

Another good example can be found - https://www.dbrnd.com/2017/03/postgresql-regexp_split_to_array-to-split-string-using-different-delimiters/

```
SELECT 
    a[1] AS DiskInfo
    ,a[2] AS DiskNumber
    ,a[3] AS MessageKeyword
FROM (
    SELECT regexp_split_to_array('Postgres Disk information , disk 2 , failed', ',')
) AS dt(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ANY operator in the JOIN condition:

```
select *
from table1 t1
  join table2 t2 on t2.type = any (t1.type);
```

Note that if the types in the table1 match multiple rows in table2, you would get duplicates (from table1) because that's how a join works. Maybe you want an EXISTS condition instead:

```
select *
from table1 t1
where exists (select * 
              from table2 t2
              where t2.type = any(t1.type));
```